# Unity 5.3.5 - Add splits/abi to Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

my current project requires me to build my App for use on x86 and ARMv7. I have a native so file which is built for use on ARMv7 but as soon as my App reaches the point where it calls the .so file, it crashes with exception:

E/AndroidRuntime( 8427): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.my-app.alpha-1/lib/x86/libVDFaceVerificationAPI-jni.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40

I've tried changing Player Settings > Device Filter to ARMv7+x86 but to no avail, the App still crashes.

Interestingly, the supplier of the so file provided me with a sample App which I can successfully run with no problems at all. This is down to the following gradle step:

splits {

abi {

enable true

reset()

include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'

universalApk true

}

}

Because I'm using Unity to build my App I don't have the ability to use the above-mentioned gradle step meaning I'm a little stuck. The supplier's .so file can successfully run on an x86 device but Unity appears to be preventing me from running it.

Does anyone have any advice as to how/if it's possible to get me over the hump with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you place the .so file in Unity?

Comment: The .so file is in an .aar file which is provided to us by a third party supplier.